# Django templates not extending properly

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to customize Django REST framework's browsable API pages from my application, as shown [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/#customizing), but the children templates seem to be ignored (incidentally, this also happens when trying to extend DRF Docs base template). This is the relevant part of the file tree:

```
├── <app>
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── <app>
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   ├── rest_framework
│   │   |   └── api.html
│   │   └── rest_framework_docs
│   │       └── docs.html
```

And even though api.html starts with `{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}` the changes made to the relevant code blocks (e.g. bootstrap_theme) are ignored and the default template is shown instead. What am i missing? Most related questions refer to errors in urls.py, but i believe this is not the case

PS: This is on Django 1.9.8

Comment: Have you set  [APP_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#app-dirs) to `True`? It might be the issue.

Comment: Yes, it comes with `True` by default since Django 1.8+ i believe, so the problem is somewhere else, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem for a while and I fixed it by adding the BASE_DIR path to the TEMPLATES dict into settings.py, like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR,
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Hope this helps, otherwise if you can share more information about your project maybe I can help more ;) (I mean: settings.py, urls, full project structure...).

Answer (score 0):

I know that it might be a bit late, but add the following to your templates settings:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates')]
```

The whole reasoning for me was the fact that I have put the templates in a different place of the one I referred too.